# Unknown LateInitializationError in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter widget which retrieves Json information from an API and displays a widget of that information. My initState is as follows:

```
class _BuildCardsWidgetState extends State<BuildCardsWidget> {
  bool display = false;
  late Resource _resource;

  Future<Resource> fetchResource(Build build) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(APIURL); <-actual url link hidden
    final response = await http.get(url); 
    var resourceReturn = json.decode(response.body);
    var resourceJson = resourceReturn[0]['resource'];
    return Resource.fromJson(resourceJson, build);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchResource(widget.build).then((value) => 
        this.setState(() {
          _resource = value;
          display = true;
        }));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ... <- _resource is used within build
```

However, whenever the program gets to the line

```
final response = await http.get(url);
```

This error is thrown:

```
The following LateError was thrown building BuildCardsWidget(dirty, state: _BuildCardsWidgetState#b3c7a):
LateInitializationError: Field '_resource' has not been initialized.
```

The thing that confuses me is this error flashes, but then right after the widget is correctly built and it runs smoothly. Any suggestions on how to fix this or on how to ignore this error since it does appear to work after the initial error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using asynchronous functions inside `initState`, if it's not properly handled with `await` in a separate function, the widget won't load your data before build your widgets. A quick and simple way to solve this is to use a `FutureBuilder()`.

```
class _BuildCardsWidgetState extends State<BuildCardsWidget> {

  Future<Resource> fetchResource(Build build) async {
     var url = Uri.parse(APIURL);  <-actual url link hidden
    var resourceReturn = json.decode(response.body);
    var resourceJson = resourceReturn[0]['resource'];
    return Resource.fromJson(resourceJson, build);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Resource>(
      future: fetchResource(build),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return SizedBox();
        }
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          /// Handle error
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have looked into FutureBuilder before and I got a similar error as in previous attemps with "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" being thrown.

Comment: Do you need to set ```display = true```? . I think you don't need it because the widgets will build only when it loads the data. I think you can remove the ```setState((){})```

Comment: I edited the answer, try and see if this will work for you

Comment: Your answer was correct, I was still calling on resource.function instead of snapshot.function. If anyone else see's this and is confused, https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data steps 3-5 explained this perfectly